# Determining position on an HTML5 canvas after zooming

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

This is a repost of [stackoverflow.com/q/10626292](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10626292) which is unanswered. 
I include sample code of the problem here: jsfiddle.net/jesusgarza/cxr6e/

Basically, after I scale the canvas the coordinates are off. If you play with the fiddle you will see that as you move to the right the offset is greater. So it seems that I have to scale back up, get the coordinate, scale down and then draw. But I don’t know where to put that code.

Comment: There are some answers in that other question, anyway if they are not correct I suggest you say what they lack and probably start a bounty on the question so it gets more attention.